# How might I design a commenting system like that on Stack Overflow?

Tags: sql, database-design

I am a big fan of the design and functionality of Stack Overflow. So, I would like to create my own design for a commenting system based on the one used for this site!

#### Questions:

- What sort of table structure should I use for storing comments?
- What SQL queries might I then use for fetching stored comments?

Comment: Oooops, two close votes?? why?

Comment: How can any of us know more about the SO architecture than you do yourself?

Comment: Mostly questions about SO itself tend to get closed. Probably it is an interesting question in itself, and it does seem to be programming related so maybe that is unfortunate but there you go

Comment: See recent SO blog "Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump": http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/

Comment: Personally I see nothing wrong with asking how a commenting system is structured.

Comment: I am just discussing this question, so that I can get an idea, that how they've developed their commenting system. I just thought that I can discuss this matter with you guys better than anyone else. If you thinks its not programming related then I can't do anything caz this question already got 4 close comments, I don't think its a too bad question to get 4 close comments within second :(

Comment: @Prashant: I've edited your question to make it answerable by someone other than the SO developers; if all you care about is SO itself then please see the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks, @Shog looks cool now,, may be the language of ma question was wrong earlier.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly obvious structure. The entities are:

```
Post: ID, Post Type (Question or Answer), Text, User ID
Question extends Post: Title
Answer extends Post:
Comment: ID, Post ID (attached to which Post), User ID, Text
```

And you can extend this easily to add tagging, editing/revisions, votes, flags and close/reopen votes.

Answer (score 2):

@cletus's answer is useful but uses "extends" which is hardly a standard relational term, so let me offer my 2 cents.

I'd assume that comments (what you're specifically asking about) are about "items", a very general category encompassing questions, answers, and maybe more things yet (though in SO comments are only about questions or answers).

So an item would be a table with a PK of ItemId, all fields common to all items (a timestamp on which it was created, a user ID as a FK on a table of users, etc) and possibly a "ItemType" field usable for picking which other table (Questions, Answers, maybe more yet) to get specific details for the specific item, if any. I'd probably index each of these as I can easily imagine looking for items in a certain range of times, posted by a certain user, &c.

A Comment would have its own PK CommentId, a FK of ItemId, a timestamp, the author's UserId, and maybe a couple more column if you allow up/down votes on comments (or even just upvotes on them a la SO), flagging, &c.

To get, say, "all comments by user IDC on items by user IDI", I'd query:

```
SELECT * FROM Comments
  JOIN Items USING (ItemId)
  WHERE Comments.UserId = @IDC
    AND Items.UserId = @IDI
```

I hope all other queries of interest are just as obvious as this one (if all interesting queries are trivially simple, this speaks well about the DB schema that makes them so;-).